# How do I combine it in 1 table?

Tags: html, css

How do I combine the table in 1? My output was this. I can't combine it so sad. Any suggestion?

```
<table class="header-table" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td><b>Drop</b> : {{$value['sequence_id']}}</td>
          <td><b>Route Code</b> : {{$value['route_no']}}</td>
          <td><b>Route Name</b> : {{$route_name}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>
                <?php
                    $getVsr = \App\Modules\Entities\VSR\VSR::where('route_no',$value['route_no'])->get();
                    // dd($getVsr);
                ?>
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>ENV</th>
      <th>VSR NO.</th>
      <th>BOX/BDL</th>
      <th>SEAL NO.</th>
      <th>PADLOCK NO.</th>
      <th>DEST-ATA</th>
      <th>DEST-ATD</th>
      <th>REMARKS</th>
      <th>RECEIVED BY/DATE</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($getVsr as $vsrVal)
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['env']}}</td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['vsr_no']}}</td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['vsr_no']}}</td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['seal_no']}}</td>
      <td>{{$vsrVal['padlock_no']}}</td>
      <td>________</td>
      <td>________</td>
      <td>________</td>
      <td>________</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

I'm not good in table. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: this is my css ----(  .header-table{
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
}       )-----

Answer (score 0):

Add another tr and inside it a td with colspan 3 and the you can place another table inside this td

```
<table class="header-table" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td><b>Drop</b> : {{$value['sequence_id']}}</td>
          <td><b>Route Code</b> : {{$value['route_no']}}</td>
          <td><b>Route Name</b> : {{$route_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <table>...</table>
          </td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So maybe you should explain better what you mean combine as 1.
The above snippet has 1 table that inside has a row with header data and then row data that are displayed in an inner table!
Can you somehow show the desired result so we can help?

Comment: Hi. slr.. May i ask if how can i merge it in 1 table? the output below are separate . i want only fix it as 1 table border . thanks for reply.

Comment: pardon . i wasnt explain it accurately.

Answer (score 0):

1.) @Konstantinos A . This is the output . Still not combine 
[image]

Comment: up up up  up up up this post

Comment: up up up up up up up up up